# comparing text matches in awk in different columns

Tags: awk

I would like to compare two text strings if they are correct and matching provided that they are in 2 different columns in a csv file. I have the values

```
"DB Instance Identifier","Engine","Instance Type","MultiAZ","Reservation ID","State","Start Time","Reserved Engine","Reserved DB Instance Type"
"alpha-db-dev","postgres","db.t4g.micro",false,"alpha-db-dev-26aug2022","active","2022-08-26","postgresql","db.t4g.micro"
"alpha-db-prod","postgres","db.t4g.small",true,"alpha-db-prod-26aug2022","active","2022-08-26","postgresql","db.t4g.small"
"beta-db-dev-primary","aurora-postgresql","db.t3.medium",false,"beta-db-dev-primary-07sep2022","active","2022-09-07","postgresql","db.t3.medium"
"beta-db-dev-secondary","aurora-postgresql","db.t3.medium",false,"beta-db-dev-secondary-07sep2022","active","2022-09-07","postgresql","db.t3.small"
"charlie-db-prod","mysql","db.t3.small",true,"charlie-db-prod-07sep2022","active","2022-09-07","sql","db.t4g.medium"
```

in the example, the first row is a header where I would like to add the term "Engine match?" and "Instance Type Match?" which would be columns 10 and 11.

Then I would like the second row and succeeding ones to check if the value in column 2 and 8 matches. In the 2nd row and print `true` in column 10 if it does, and `false` if not.

I would also like to check if the values in column 3 and 9 are matching following the same logic above but print the result in column 11.

Desired Output:

```
"DB Instance Identifier","Engine","Instance Type","MultiAZ","Reservation ID","State","Start Time","Reserved Engine","Reserved DB Instance Class","Engine match?","Instance Type Match?"
"alpha-db-dev","postgres","db.t4g.micro",false,"alpha-db-dev-26aug2022","active","2022-08-26","postgresql","db.t4g.micro","true","true"
"alpha-db-prod","postgres","db.t4g.small",true,"alpha-db-prod-26aug2022","active","2022-08-26","postgresql","db.t4g.small","true","true"
"beta-db-dev-primary","aurora-postgresql","db.t3.medium",false,"beta-db-dev-primary-07sep2022","active","2022-09-07","postgresql","db.t3.medium","false","true"
"beta-db-dev-secondary","aurora-postgresql","db.t3.medium",false,"beta-db-dev-secondary-07sep2022","active","2022-09-07","postgresql","db.t3.small","true","false"
"charlie-db-prod","mysql","db.t3.small",true,"charlie-db-prod-07sep2022","active","2022-09-07","sql","db.t4g.medium","false","false"
```

This is a very bad attempt as I'm still learning the ropes of awk.
Attempt:

```
    NR == 1 { print $0, "\"Engine match?\",\"DB Instance Type Match?\""; next } #prints the column 10 and 11 header
    {
        min = $1 #skips the first line
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($10 != $11) { #I'm not sure how to call columns here
                #I'm not sure how to put in the result true / false in column 10 and 11
            }
        }
        print $0, min
    }
```

Any help or idea would be great. I would also appreciate if the breakdown of the awk script would be given so I can study it further for another use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)`  loops over all fields from 2 to the end of the line. Your code compares `$10` to `$11` NF-1 times. That in combination with `min = $1 #skips the first line` tells me you're confusing the `NF` and `NR` variables (see the man page for what each means) and also think you need to write a loop to process all the input lines - you don't, awk does that for you. Text-processing code in other languages looks like this pseudo-code:

```
while ( read line ) {
    ++NR
    NF = 0
    while ( field = next word in line ) {
       fields[++NF] = field
    }
    print line
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        print NR, NF, fields[i]
    }
}
```

but awk provides most of that for you and so the code you actually write in awk would just be:

```
    print $0
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        print NR, NF, $i
    }
```

Hope that helps with the basic awk understanding.

Now to your question -

To add 2 fields to your data after the 9th field would be:

```
{ $9 = $9 FS "" FS ""; $0=$0 }
```

> the first row is a header where I would like to add the term "Engine
> match?" and "Instance Type Match?" which would be columns 10 and 11.

```
NR==1 { $10="\"Engine match?\""; $11="\"Instance Type Match?\"" }
```

> Then I would like the second row and succeeding ones to check if the
> value in column 2 and 8 matches. In the 2nd row and print true in
> column 10 if it does, and false if not.

```
NR > 1 { $10 = ( $2 == $8 ? "true" : "false" ) }
```

> I would also like to check if the values in column 3 and 9 are
> matching following the same logic above but print the result in column
> 11.

```
NR > 1 { $11 = ( $3 == $9 ? "true" : "false" ) }
```

All together:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { $9 = $9 FS "" FS ""; $0=$0 }
    NR==1 {
        $10 = "\"Engine match?\""
        $11 = "\"Instance Type Match?\""
    }
    NR > 1 {
        $10 = ( $2 == $8 ? "true" : "false" )
        $11 = ( $3 == $9 ? "true" : "false" )
    }
    { print }
' file
```

The only non-obvious parts to the above are:

1. Assigning a value to or otherwise modifying $9 (or any field) causes awk to reconstruct $0, replacing all FSs with OFSs
2. Assigning to or otherwise modifying $0 causes awk to re-split $0 into fields.

Look:

```
$ echo "foo" | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NF, i, "<" $i ">"}'
1 1 <foo>

$ echo "foo" | awk '{$1=$1 FS "bar"; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NF, i, "<" $i ">"}'
1 1 <foo bar>
```

Note above that there's still just 1 field in $0 after modifying $1, now "change" $0 to cause field splitting to reoccur:

```
$ echo "foo" | awk '{$1=$1 FS "bar"; $0=$0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NF, i, "<" $i ">"}'
2 1 <foo>
2 2 <bar>
```

and NOW we have an extra field.

So assigning to $9 doesn't add fields to $0, it just makes $9 contain more text. It's assigning to $0 afterwards that turns that new text we added into new fields. For this to work it's important that FS and OFS have the same value so that when assigning to a field (which triggers replacing all FSs with OFSs) we don't change what separates fields so that when we then assign to $0 (which triggers field splitting at each FS) we still have the same separator value in $0 as we started with.

Comment: Truly another outstanding breakdown Ed! Thank you so much. And yes you are right!  I am still a bit confused with the variables from awk and I'm finding myself staring at it quite too often. Still reading up on a lot of resources on this. Truly appreciate your breakdowns here as this would definitely help me pattern more of my future development on this script I'm working on. Greatly appreciate you Ed. Thank you so much!

Comment: I highly recommend anyone doing text processing in Unix get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.